# Sort DB records with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sorting, records, jdbctemplate

How to Sort DB records in DB table with JdbcTemplate?

What is the best solution, should *execute* method be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JdbcTemplate` simply executes the SQL that you provide to it in the `execute` method, so use the standard SQL method: `ORDER BY`

Comment: so if i want to sort table by column1,expression should looks like :
jdbcTemplate.execute("select * from MyTable ORDER BY column1 ASC"
?
or what method instead of execute?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The ordering should be done by the database in your SQL query. The correct way to execute queries using `JdbcTemplate` is the `execute` method.

Answer (score 2):

Data in a database table should be considered unordered, you can select data with a particular ordering, also, use SimpleJdbcTemplate in preference to JdbcTemplate, the same methods are available using [`SimpleJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html#getJdbcOperations%28%29).

For example this code snippet will give you an ordered list of all the values in column1, assuming they are strings

```
final SimpleJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(datasource);
final List<String> data = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT column1 FROM MyTable ORDER BY column1 ASC", new ParameterizedSingleColumnRowMapper<String>());
```

Comment: i mentioned to order db table, not to get ordered list

Comment: As I said, data in a database table should be considered **unordered**, a database table is a set of data, not a list

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways, though the JdbcTemplate is incidental to them. The first would be to include an "order by" clause in your query. Otherwise you're looking at sorting whatever kind of collection your call returned.